# How to measure Random Forest classifier accuracy?

Tags: python, classification, random-forest

So, I am using a Random Forest classifier to make predictions using this code:

```
# Import Random Forest
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

# Create a Gaussian Classifier
clf_two=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=3)

# Train the model using the training sets
clf_two.fit(emb_train, ytrain.ravel())

y_pred_two=clf_two.predict(emb_test)
```

I want to find out the accuracy of my classifier and tried doing this:

```
# Import scikit-learn metrics module for accuracy calculation
from sklearn import metrics

# Model Accuracy
print("Accuracy:", metrics.accuracy_score(ytrain, y_pred_two))
```

The problem is that `y_pred_two` is a row vector of size `(5989,)` and `ytrain` is a column vector of size `(16128, 1)`. So there is a size mismatch between the two and I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [16128, 5989]
```

Is it still possible to measure the accuracy if the sizes for `y_pred_two` and `ytrain` are different or am I doing something wrong? But that's how training and testing data was given to me.

Your quick help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the issue is simply that you are trying to evaluate the accuracy of predicted values obtained by running the model on test samples with target labels of the train dataset.

You just need to load or generate the test set labels (ytest) and run:

`print("Accuracy:", metrics.accuracy_score(ytest, y_pred_two))`

Comment: How can I generate `ytest` or test set labels. I am given `emb_train` of size `(16128, 1000)`, `ytrain` of size `(16128, 1)` and `emb_test` of size `(5989, 1000)`. These are the three variables I am using.

Comment: I don't know what task are you solving, but it seems to me that you might be expected to generate the test outputs as a result? Since you were not given the expected test target values, split some of your train data into a validation dataset and evaluate the model accuracy using this dataset (but do not train it using this validation subset!). Scikitlearn package has some functions for this, e.g. train_test_split.

Comment: But I need to do the final prediction on `emb_test` so it must have `(5989,)` entries. If I use train_test_split wouldn't that make the test data size different than `5989` depending on if I make the test size to be 30%, 40%, 50% etc? If I am understanding incorrectly, can you show what you mean.